# Is Argothian Elder a Druid?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Argothian Elder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Argothian%20Elder) is listed on a lot of websites with the Druid creature type, but the card only lists "Elf".

Is Argothian Elder a Druid too?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rule 108.1 states:

> 108.1. Use the Oracle™ card reference when determining a card’s wording. A card’s Oracle text can be found using the Gatherer card database at Gatherer.Wizards.com

This means that the text on Gatherer is correct regardless of what is printed on the card.  This is because older cards have been changed, usually to maintain their functionality while the rules have continued to evolve.

Gatherer lists [Argothian Elder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Argothian%20Elder)'s type as "Creature — Elf Druid", so it is a druid. Older cards only had a single creature type, in the Grand Creature Type Update most older cards got updated to the newer   structure used today.

Comment: The reason for the change was probably the [Grand Creature Type Update](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Grand_Creature_Type_Update)

Comment: Mana-producing elves (including ones that untap lands) are generally druids, so this change was certainly consistent.

Comment: @Jefromi: interesting, I never realized. [And indeed](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=|[%22add%22]|[untap]&type=+[%22Creature%22]&subtype=+[%22Elf%22]) it seems that almost all mana-producing elfs are Druids. There's a handful of "Elf Shamans" and one "Zombie Elf" and one "Warrier Elf", but the overwhelming majority is Druids. TIL.

Comment: @Cascabel or shamans, but the massive majority were typed druid.